# Dimension of solution space of n:th order linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am very confused about some of the theory I'm reading on ordinary differential equations. I hope someone can help to clarify.

Having an n:th order homogeneous linear equation $$x^{(n)}(t) + p_1(t)x^{(n-1)}(t) + \cdots + p_n(t)x(t) = 0, $$ there is a theorem saying that the solution space of this equation has dimension $n$. This "follows immediately" from a lemma stating that if we let $t_0 \in I$ and $x_1(t), \dots, x_m(t)$ be solutions of the above equation, then the set of those solutions are linearly independent iff the vectors $\bar{x}_1(t_0), \dots, \bar{x}_m(t_0)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\bar{x}_i(t_0) = (x_i(t_0), x'_i(t_0),\dots, x^{(n-1)}_i(t_0)).$

I cannot see how the theorem follows from this lemma.

If the solution space has dimension $n$, then that means there are $n$ linearly independent solutions, doesn't it? But in the lemma we assume $m$ different solutions, and that is the first thing that confuses me.

And these $m$ solutions are linearly independent, meaning that $a_1x_1(t) + \cdots + a_mx_m(t) = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_m = 0$, if, according to the lemma, we have that $\bar{x}_1(t_0),\dots, \bar{x}_m(t_0)$ are linearly independent. But what tells me that they are?

Comment: Let $m$ be $n$ in the lemma...